# Implementing filter with concat and map in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

```
filter1 :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter1 p = concat.map box
              where box x
                    | p x       = [x]
                    | otherwise = []
```

I don't understand this solution. 
map apply box to all the elements of the list and if p x == True it's puts the element on a list of a single element and then concat unificates everything? concat unify everything at the end or one by one?

Thanks! I hope somebody understands this

Comment: What do you mean by "*at the end or one by one*"? Haskell uses lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 7):

It is very hard to discern from your question what you are actually asking. Please try to phrase your questions clearly. I will just explain how the function works, and hope that this explanation will address whatever it is that you're actually asking.

---

First, `map box` is applied to the input list. Every call to `box` will either return `[x]`, for those `x` that satisfy the predicate `p`; or an empty list, for those `x` that do not satisfy the predicate. Thus, the result of `map box` will be a list of empty lists and singleton lists.

Let's consider an example. Let's say that:

```
input_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
p = odd
```

Then:

```
map box input_list = [ [1], [], [3], [], [5] ]
```

The first element `1` was mapped to `[1]`, because `p 1 == True`. The second element `2` was mapped to `[]`, because `p 2 == False`. And so on.

After that, `concat` is applied to this list of lists. It concatenates all those small lists into a big list. So in our example:

```
concat [ [1], [], [3], [], [5] ] = [1] ++ [] ++ [3] ++ [] ++ [5] = [1,3,5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Well imagine that we have for example five elements:

```
[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]
```

and that `p` holds for `x2`, `x3` and `x5`. Then we perform a mapping as follows:

```
              map box [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]
------------------------------------------
= [box x1, box x2, box x3, box x4, box x5]
```

Since `p` holds for `x2`, `x3` and `x5`, it means that `box` returns an empty list for `x1` and `x4`, and a singleton list with the original list for `x2`, `x3` and `x5`, so:

```
  [box x1, box x2, box x3, box x4, box x5]
------------------------------------------
=               [[], [x2], [x3], [], [x5]]
```

Then if we apply the `concat`, the empty lists (`[]`) will not add any elements to the result, so the original elements are "filtered out", whereas the content of the singleton lists - the elements for which `p` holds - are added to the list, so:

```
  concat [[], [x2], [x3], [], [x5]]
-----------------------------------
=                      [x2, x3, x5]
```

So by mapping elements that we want to filter out to empty lists, and elements that we want to keep to singleton lists with that element, and concatenating those elements, we manage to filter out the elements we do not want. Nevertheless this for of filtering is - if not optimized - not very efficient, since we box and unbox all the elements we want.

Note that Haskell is a lazy language, so if you somehow `filter1` some elements, then this is *not* performed, unless you need the result. Furthermore both `map` and `concat` are lazy as well (like all functions). Here this means that if we are for instance interested in the *i*-th element of the result, we will not calculate the entire list.